# Teleporting an entity behind a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a morph command with command blocks but whenever I try to use `^` the mob just moves up and down when I try to move my camera. I can't figure out how to get the head to move while I have an offset.
For example, something like:

```
execute at USERNAME run tp @e[name=clone] ^ ~ ^
```

Comment: It is not possible to mix relative (~) and rotational (^) coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rotated ~ 0` to essentially ignore the pitch of the player when teleporting the entity `^ ^ ^-1` (1 block behind, or any desired offset) the player so that it does not move up or down whenever the player looks up or down.

Here's an example:

```
execute at <player> rotated ~ 0 run tp @e[tag = clone] ^ ^ ^-1
```

---

If you still want the entity to look up or down if the player looks up or down, you can `execute as` and `at` the entity that has the `clone` tag, use `rotated as <player>` and `/tp` the entity to its relative position with relative rotation:

```
execute at <player> rotated ~ 0 run tp @e[tag = clone] ^ ^ ^-1

execute as @e[tag = clone] at @s rotated as <player> run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: Its good but I need to keep the need to keep the rotation for example :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQ7NHCrN7bg

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover that specific case, @James_7559

Comment: It doesn't work even if I fix it, there is no thing for teleporting it behind it just the same as I already had. Thank you.